# Entity framework connection string for WPF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

Our application is currently connected to SQL CE but, we have to make it work with both SQL CE and SQL Express.
We are using entity framework(model first). And its a windows application.

How to write connection string for SQL Server?

I found below on msdn site at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx but, I am sure it won't be localdb.

```
<add name="BlogContext"  
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/BloggingModel.csdl| 
                                                       res://*/BloggingModel.ssdl| 
                                                       res://*/BloggingModel.msl; 
                                           provider=System.Data.SqlClient 
                                           provider connection string= 
                                               &quot;data source=(localdb)\v11.0; 
                                               initial catalog=Blogging; 
                                               integrated security=True; 
                                               multipleactiveresultsets=True;&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: you want the entity model to CRUD to two DBs simultaneously? I just want to be clear on the intention.

Comment: @Neurothustra Some machines will be connected to SQLCE, some others would be connected to SQL Express

Answer (score 0):

you can use the data source to specify whether Windows Authentication or Server Authentication.

If you are using Windows Authentication you can give

```
data source =. //(local)
```

or

```
data source =.\SQLEXPRES
```

or

```
data source =YourPcName\SQLEXPRESS
```

If you are using Server authentication

```
data source=serverName
```

Reference provides in detail about connection string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx

Comment: The application would be used by us and our clients. We do use windows authentication but, not sure what they are using and anyways both our and their employees won't be in the same windows system.

Comment: Your wpf application hosted on the server.?

Comment: Its hosted on cloud. Its a windows application, not a browser application.